# Create a file and specify permissions in PHP without race conditions?

Tags: php, security

How can I create a file and specify the permissions without introducing race conditions with PHP?

The solution proposed elsewhere:

```
touch($file);
chmod($file, 0600);
```

Is not acceptable as there is a window of time between when the file is created and when the permissions are set.

Comment: How about [**`fopen`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with predefined [**`umask`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)?

Comment: The docs don't make it seem like PHP's fopen accepts a umask :\

Comment: From what I understood you would set the umask first and when the file is created using the fopen it would use the default mask.